# problemas al iniciar sesion con pass_verify php

Tags: php, mysql

Pues eso eh probado de todo pero no logro descubrir por que no puedo hacer funcionar pass_verify al iniciar sesion.

Aqui un poco de lo que venido haciendo
Guardo la contraseña en la bd con lo siguiente:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-add'])) {
    $user = $_POST['userTxt'];
    $pass = $_POST['passTxt'];
    $passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario,pass_usuarios) values (?,?)");
    $sql ->bind_param("ss",$user,$passHash);
    $sql->execute();
}
```

El registro se guarda con una cadena de 60 caracteres. Tengo configurado la respectiva tabla eb varchar y para que se puedan agregar hasta 250 caracteres

Para iniciar sesion uso lo siguiente

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $user = $_POST["userTxt"];
    $pass = $_POST["passTxt"];
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?");
    $query->bind_param("s", $user);
    $query->execute();
    $resultado = $query->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    if (isset($resultado['usuario']) == true) {
        if (!password_verify($pass, $resultado['pass_usuarios'])) {
            echo 'pass no existe';
        } else {
            echo 'existe';
        }
    }else{
echo 'usuario no existe';
}
```

No importa lo que haga siempre me sale el mensaje de que la pass no existe curiosamente si cambio el pass_verify

por esto

```
if (password_verify($pass, $resultado['pass_usuarios'])) {
            echo 'pass no existe';
        } else {
            echo 'existe';
        }
```

es decir quito el signo de exclamacion al inicio de password_verify en cambio solo me sale que existe, pese a escribir mal la contraseña. Algún consejo no veo que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Vamos por parte. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($resultado);` en tu código? y ¿qué sentido tiene hacer esto: `if (isset($resultado['usuario']) == true) {`?

Comment: esto para verificar si existe el usuario. if (isset($resultado['usuario']) == true) Y el otro problema ya lo resolvi gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código y a mí me funciona. Prueba a conectarte a otra base de datos con una tabla `usuarios` más simple:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  usuario varchar(31),
  pass_usuarios varchar(255)
  );
```

A ver si el problema va a estar en algún disparador que te está volviendo a encriptar la contraseña sin que te estés percatando, o que tu campo contraseña no tenga la suficiente longitud para almacenar el hash completo...

Comment: Gracias ya lo eh resuelto en efecto al ver que todo el codigo estaba aparantemente bien decidi empezar de 0 borrando todo y no eh vuelto a tener problemas no se si fue po algun bug o es que me equivoque en alguna otra parte del codigo, pero ya consegui solucionarlo gracias.